# Difference Between "are engaged" and "are engaging"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

While reading an article, I came across this sentence

> French President Emmanuel Macron has said he is sure Syrian fighters were operating in Nagorno-Karabakh, where Armenia and Azerbaijan are engaged in heavy fighting.

My question is about the part of the sentence that reads "are engaged in heavy fighting." What I want to know is what is the difference between "are engaged" and "are engaging"? Intuitively, the second one makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sense of this sentence `engaged` implies it is an ongoing conflict that has been happening for some time. It can also be used in past tense. Whilst `engaging` implies there is a sudden outbreak of conflict.

Consider these two example sentences:

> During the war, we engaged with the enemy forces near the river for 3 days straight.

and:

> "We have heard reports that the marines are engaging the enemeny soldiers as we speak. Is this true?" the interviewer asked the general.